# Whats wrong with kohana's view variable scope?

Tags: variables, view, kohana, scope

To quickly summarize my problem, I simply copied the example of (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) into one of my views and wondered why it was nothing echoed on my screen.

Here the example of php.net:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

I expected '3' on my screen but $b returned still '2'..
Well I tested this behavior about 3 hours with different examples and it seems that kohana does some tricky things.
I thought Kohana only extracts the View::_data into the local scope and everything would be ok but now I have no clue about it.

Could somebody explain me that behaviour?

[How can I wrap PHP legacy code in Kohana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667112/how-can-i-wrap-php-legacy-code-in-kohana) couldn't help me..

Btw, sorry for my language mistakes!

**UPDATE:**

I know using globals is bad but my clean approach didn't work yesterday..
But now I don't know why everything works again, maybe there was a caching problem.

But besides that I understood the mistake of my given example, thank you.
Seems that it has nothing to do with output buffering..

Comment: What do you need? I believe, there is a quick and elegant way to do it without ugly globals.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely you're not in the global scope. So all the variables should be prepended with `global` like

```
<?php
global $a = 1;
global $b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

PS: global variables are the root of all evil. Everything can and should be implemented without them.